# producer consumer

Tags: android, semaphore, producer-consumer

i have an application which has a part where some variables are written and read at very high frequency.
Is there any need of a semaphores or locks(Data consistency is not a concern in this case).Is there any chance of application terminating or crashing.I dont want to get into threads,semaphores and stuff as it is a trivial part of application.

Answer (score 1):

There is not nearly enough information in your question to give you an accurate answer, but in general - if you have multiple threads, and one produces data, one consumes it, then yes, you will need synchronization.

You could use a `BlockingQueue`, or just a simple synchronized object, whatever is appropriate in your case... but you will need some synchronization, or else you risk random hard-to-reproduce crashes.

This is even more important when dealing with multi-core systems, which are becoming popular now.